# Can you report real-time visitors to your website using Mixpanel

Tags: real-time, reporting, mixpanel, web-analytics

I am looking for a web analytics tool where I can see in real time the number of users as well as other metrics for my website. I am currently using GA4 but the reporting is very static for real time stats so I am looking for a tool which has more flexability and I can customise the reports and what matrics I can report in real time.

I want to be able to report in real time visualisations the number of users on or visiting my site as well as other metrics like average session duration.